# org.renjin.cran libraries missing from repositories

Tags: java, maven, cran, renjin

Attempts to update our maven dependencies have recently uncovered a problem.

Many errors are thrown, similar to this one: Error downloading org.renjin.cran:BH:1.62.0-1-b8

It seems that these dependencies were removed from repositories. Note following the above error that https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/renjin/cran/ no longer contains a BH folder, and https://nexus.bedatadriven.com/content/groups/public/org/renjin/cran/BH/ contains only signatures of files, but no actual library .pom files.

This is weird because http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/BH/1.69.0-1 specifically claims that those packages exist.

I have been unable to find any information about planned changes to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a configuration problem at nexus.bedatadriven.com. The artifacts are again available.